# How to identify and draw lines using objects mask

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw patern of lines using this kind of images, I don't know how but here is the desired input and output.

For the language I'm using Python 3.10.x with cv2 and skimage.morphology

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Thanks

I tried Hough lines detection but it didn't  work as expected.